# Sklearn: linear regression to predict data

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have train dataframe. It's a part of them

```
date    city    brand   model   price   count
2016-03 moscow  bmw 5-series    1 млн - 2 млн   5
2016-05 moscow  bmw 5-series    500 тыс - 1 млн 3
2016-06 moscow  bmw 5-series    1 млн - 2 млн   4
2016-09 moscow  bmw 5-series    до 200 тыс  4
```

I need to predict it to `2016-12` test dataframe

```
date    city    brand   model
2016-12 moscow  bmw 5-series
```

I try to use `linear regression`

```
X = pd.read_excel('result_drom2.xlsx')
X_predict = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
y = pd.DataFrame()

y['count'] = X['count']
del X['count']
label = LabelEncoder()
def cat_to_num(df, column):
    dicts = {}
    label.fit(df[column].drop_duplicates())
    dicts[column] = list(label.classes_)
    df[column] = label.transform(df[column])

cat_to_num(X, 'date')    
cat_to_num(X, 'city')
cat_to_num(X, 'brand')
cat_to_num(X, 'model')
cat_to_num(X, 'price')

cat_to_num(X_predict, 'date') 
cat_to_num(X_predict, 'city')
cat_to_num(X_predict, 'brand')
cat_to_num(X_predict, 'model')
cat_to_num(X_predict, 'price')

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
y_predict = model.predict(X_predict)
```

But I have got a `[ 2.17593916]`. And all data are different, but all values have been got by me are between `1.5 and 2.7`. Is it correct and how can I values, that will be some in common with last data?